# How to measure heat transfer and heat dissipation in a kitchen?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, home-experiment, heat

I am a chemistry beginner just starting to coming to grips with stoves and Bunsen burners.

I would like to know, what kind of instrument can I use to measure the amount of heat transferred from a kitchen stove to a pot, in, units of heat per second (what are heat units?), and, does it depend on the height of the pot above the stove (space in between), and, heat dissipation in the pot stand metal and in the pot metal (how would I measure this, too, and what units would I use to measure this, for example to measure heat dissipation)?

Answer (score 1):

> [OP] I would like to know, what kind of instrument can I use to measure the amount of heat transferred from a kitchen stove to a pot [...]

A thermometer placed in the pot filled with water. Ideally, you would stir so that the temperature is almost uniform. You would need to know the heat capacity of water at the temperature ranges you encounter, and how much water is in the pot. You would also have to do a separate experiment to check the heat capacity of the pot.

> [OP...] in, units of heat per second (what are heat units?),

Heat is transfer of thermal energy, so it has the same units as energy (e.g. Joule).

> [OP...] and, does it depend on the height of the pot above the stove (space in between),

Yes. There is a German expression "einen Zahn zulegen" (roughly to add a tooth), which means to speed things up. Pots were suspended over open fire with a ratchet mechanism, and you would lower them to make things cook faster (or burn, if you overdo it).

[image]

Source: Von Axel Ropte, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=17205393

> [OP...] and, hear dissipation in the pot stand metal she in the pot metal (how would I measure this, too, and what units would I use to measure this (for example, to measure heat dissipation))?

This is a bit too garbled to understand.